# Plotting a Spectral Clustering Model in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, cluster-analysis

I need to plot and visualize the outcomes of a Spectral Clustering using different colors in scikit.
I'd want to achieve something similar to the following picture:
[image: plotting of clustering algorithm]

I have a dataframe with approximately 80000 rows and 17 columns, and ran
`clustering = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=17).fit(df)`

on it.
I saw people visualizing their results using e.g.

`plt.scatter(clustering[:0], clustering[:1],  c = clustering.labels_)`

Problem is: I get a

`TypeError: 'SpectralClustering' object is not subscriptable`

error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think i got it! :)
I tried to scatter the clustering itself, instead of the dataframe. And instead of using df[:,0] etc. for dataframes you'd have to use:

```
df.iloc[:,0]
```

for anyone with a similar question.

Thanks! :)